# Vim 7.4: Issue with popup menu: first item becomes unselected

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I used very old Vim 7.3.46 before (on Windows), now I tried Vim 7.4, and I have an issue with popup-menu.

Say, I have popup-menu with three items: `one`, `two`, `three`.

In Vim 7.3, when I type a part of word, first menuitem keeps being selected, so, I can just type <kbd>o</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and `one` is inserted in the text.

But in Vim 7.4, first item selected just when popup menu is shown, but when I type at least one symbol, selection goes away, and I need for one more keystroke `<Down>` or `<C-n>`.

This happens on different kinds of completion (provided by different plugins), so, seems to be common issue.

I have already read this [Vim tip](http://goo.gl/J9Klv0), and similar mappings are already used in my completion plugins. And they work perfectly in Vim 7.3, but fail to work in Vim 7.4.

How can I make it behave like Vim 7.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to the Vim-dev mailing list, and, after all, this issue is fixed since 7.4.018.